# Is there any way to solve this array problem using the approach i tried to use?

Tags: java, arrays

https://leetcode.com/studyplan/leetcode-75/

You have a long flowerbed in which some of the plots are planted, and some are not. However, flowers cannot be planted in **adjacent** plots.

Given an integer array `flowerbed` containing `0`'s and `1`'s, where `0` means empty and `1` means not empty, and an integer `n`, return `true` *if* `n` *new flowers can be planted in the* `flowerbed` *without violating the no-adjacent-flowers rule and* `false` *otherwise*.

```
public class Solution {
    public static boolean canPlaceFlowers(int[] flowerbed, int n) {
        boolean b=false;
        int[] empty = new int[flowerbed.length];
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < flowerbed.length; i++) {
            if (flowerbed[i] != 1) {
                empty[k] = i;
                k++;
            }

        }
        int h=0;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            for (h=0;h < empty.length; h++) {
                int v = empty[h] - 1>=0?empty[h] - 1:0;
                int x = empty[h] + 1<=flowerbed.length-1?empty[h] + 1:0;
                if (flowerbed[empty[h]] == 0 && flowerbed[x] == 0 && flowerbed[v] == 0) {
                    b = true;
                    flowerbed[empty[h]]=1;
                    empty[h]=0;

                } else
                    continue;
            }
        }
        if(empty.length==h)
        {
            b = false;
        }
        if(n ==0)
        {
            b = true;
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be overlooking some edge cases, and are overcomplicating your solution by creating an additional `empty` array.  You should be able to solve this linearly, with one pass through the `flowerbed` array.

- You can place a flowerpot in the first position or last position if the adjacent position is empty.
- You can place a flowerpot in a middle position if both it and its two adjacent neighbors are empty.
- When you place a flowerpot, it affects the availability of your next flowerpot.
- It is possible to have a flowerbed with only one pot.

Comment: @SanjitPandit Your welcome.  Remember to habitually `upvote` questions and answers you find helpful anywhere, and `accept`  the best answer to questions you ask.

Comment: i dont have much reputations to upvote :( sorry